# Does a ring isomorphism between two $F$-algebras must be a $F$-linear transformation

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ and $B$ are two finite dimensional $F$-algebra. 
If $\theta$ is a ring isomorphism between $A$ and $B$, 
does $\theta$ must be a $F$-linear transformation?

Comment: $A=B=F=\Bbb C$, $\theta$ complex conjugation?

Comment: Not at all. Simple counterexample. $F=\Bbb C=A=B$, so that $A$ and $B$ are one-dimensional $F$-algebras. Take $\theta$ to be complex conjugation. Since it doesn’t leave elements of $F$ fixed, it’s not $F$-linear.